# set negative color to Android View?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

Can we set a negative color for an Android view? Actually, my project requires an Android map in "night mode" instead of "Satellite" or "Street view" mode. It has taken me a half of a day to investigate this, but I have found no solution. I think we can set a negative color to view so we can make "night mode" in an Android map. Does anyone an idea, any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing you mean "colored like a photo negative", i.e. *inverted* colors, not RGB values less than zero.

Comment: @tai.tran2008 I am trying to do samething,did u find any solution for this.

Comment: @tai.tran ok thank you,if u find any solution try to post the solution,I will post if I do.Thanks.